# How is Subsurface Scattering calculated when doing a Cycles texture bake?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

I have seen (but not sure) that for instance reflective parts on glossy materials are rendered along face normals during a bake (as there is no camera to point to).

But how is it defined for SSS ?